# Trimester percentage 22% due to an accident. How to explain it to employers? How will it affect internship and job opportunities?

Tags: graduate-school, masters, computer-science, job, international-students

I am an international student currently pursuing my Master's program in Computer Science that follows the trimester system. Before the beginning of the trimester, I had an accident but I decided to continue with the trimester. However, I left my trimester in between as it became much worse. As a result of which I was not able to sit for my final exams and got 22% in my trimester and took a break. I am planning to withdraw from the courses which I took the last term on medical grounds so that I can get my money back with the academic penalty.

I took one year off from the program and after a full recovery, I came back again this February to continue with my Masters Program.

If they do not refund the money, they will keep the grade as it is and it will look terrible on my transcript. How do I explain this to my prospective employers? How will it affect my chances of an internship?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are withdrawing then you are continuing... Which?

Comment: let me re-edit the question @SolarMike

Comment: What do you mean by "_I am back after one year to continue with my program_"? Are you back now? Or you will be back??

Comment: I am back after I took on a year off from the Master's program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anybody can have an unexpected accident interrupt their life, like getting run over by a bus or struck down by a dangerous disease.

If you withdraw from the courses for medical reasons, your university will likely adjust your transcript in some way that reflects that as well (e.g., deleting courses or marking them withdrawn) rather than simply leaving a bad mark that looks like you simply failed.  That will help.

Whether or not your university adjusts your transcript, however, if you feel comfortable sharing some information about your accident, most employers you'd want to work for will not hold it against you that you were run over by a bus.  In this case, I would advise three steps:

1. Include a very brief note on your resume explaining the gap (e.g., "Took an extra year to graduate due to injury in an accident."). This will help get you past initial filtering.
2. Be prepared to say a little more about it if asked during an interview. You might even turn this into a positive by noting how you've worked through adversity.
3. Don't let it be a big part, however, as it shouldn't be an important part of what you will contribute at your workplace.  Even if you need a significant physical accommodation (e.g., your accident has left you partially paralyzed), with a good employer that should be an afterthought of how to arrange your work environment rather than a consideration in hiring you.

Some types of accident, however, will likely prejudice many employers against you (e.g., overdosing on heroin, failed suicide attempt). Whether or not this is justified, you should expect that if you do *not* provide information about your accident, some employers will fill in the blank with their worst imaginings.